# How to handle video views playback inside list view in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have a list of items with a Video URL in each row.I have used React-Native-Video component for Video view.

```
<TouchableOpacity
         style={styles.fullScreen}
         onPress={() => this.setState({ paused: !this.state.paused })}
 >
   <Video source={{ uri: rowData.podcastUrl }}   // URL
        ref={(ref) => {
 // Store reference
        this.player = ref
         ......
         ......                           
     }}  
   paused={true}                                   
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Above code is inside renderMyList() function which is called on the rendering of each row.

When I load my UI all the videos are either in play mode or stopped based on 'paused' state false or true(whatever I pass in above. But I want to properly handle the play/pause of individual video(list item).I have maintained a  paused state variable.

Please suggest some sample code.

Comment: Did you figure out any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to let only one video to play any given moment you can do something like below

```
onPress={() => { this.setState({ playing: 'someUniqueIdForThisVideo'}) }}
```

And check if that video is playing

```
paused={this.state.playing !== 'videoIdOrSomething'}
```

If you want multiple videos to be played you can do something like below

```
onPress={() => { this.setState({ ['someUniqueIdForThisVideo']: true}) }}
```

And check state like below

```
paused={this.state['someUniqueIdForThisVideo'] !== true}
```

This is just to give you a rough idea. You need to implement some sort of logic to set state to false if its already playing.